# Realistic Mobile Screen Resolutions

Tags: css, html, mobile

Is there a Matrix anywhere to get realistic screen availability for the most common phones which take into account the screen resolution available with toolbars visible?

We need to develop a scrolling site for mobile/tablet and although we are trying to make the css as fluid as possible the brief relies on background imagery which means we need a variety of media queries to switch the images for the best experience - a realistic resolution guide would be really helpful.

Cheers

Comment: Is one of the answer good enough for acceptance?

Comment: @RobertFricke Well, I wouldn't consider any of these answers to the OP's question. He/she (and I) are looking for a matrix of screen sizes based on usage data and the answers were "here's how to view your site on different screen sizes" and "here's how to write some media queries of some random screen sizes with zero context." Which of these responses would you consider an actual response to what the OP asked? I would say a grand total of zero.

Answer (score 14):

In Google Chrome, open developer tools by pressing F12, and click on the gear icon to go to Settings -> Overrides, turn on 'User Agent', and select your desired device - with 'Device Matrix' you can customize screen size and more.

Answer (score 8):

Check out http://screensiz.es/phone .
You can order phones or tablets by screen size, aspect ratio and popularity.

Also check out screencast in chrome canary dev tools.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/mobile/

What I am still looking for is something like [google's *browsersize*](http://browsersize.googlelabs.com/) but for mobile screen.

---

**Update:**

Google Labs Browser Size is now part of Google Analytics

For up to date datas check https://design.google.com/devices/ (AKA now as https://material.io/tools/devices/)

Answer (score 5):

@media (min-width: 1200px) {

@media (max-width: 980px) {

@media (max-width: 979px) {

@media (min-width: 980px) {

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px){

@media (max-width: 768px) {

@media (max-width: 767px) {

@media (max-width: 480px) {

Should be the **standards**

Comment: A good output of resolutions, although an explanation why these should be the standards would be nice

Answer (score 4):

I think you should definitely try this website : http://responsivetools.com/

It will give you a quick idea of how you site looks like for different mobile and tablet resolution.

Comment: A best way to check this nowadays would be screencast in chrome canary dev tools. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/mobile/

Answer (score 1):

There are many online services where you can view you site "through" a phone's display, with the resolutions specified.

For example: [mobilephoneemulator](http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/)

Comment: Thanks - also looks useful - limited range of devices though.

Answer (score 1):

Statcounter probably provides the best number crunching on screen sizes and many other stats. Their page always gives me loading problems, so I prefer to find someone that has quoted their stats, than going directly to the source, like this blogger:

http://www.satya-weblog.com/2013/07/desktop-laptop-mobile-screen-resolution-most-common-worldwide.html

Hope that is a more direct answer to your question!

Answer (score 0):

We'll you might want to try going here: http://cartoonized.net/cellphone-screen-resolution.php it basically gives you the best resolution depending on types of phones.

Answer (score 0):

This is a list for all known CSS @media property for mobile devices + several desktop resolution that can be used.

These include Android, iPhone, iPad, Google Nexus, LG, Samsung, Nokia, HTC, Motorola, Sony and all the famous brands.

Look on [GitHub](https://github.com/CreativForm/Realistic-Mobile-Screen-Resolutions)

```
@media all and (max-width: 2560px){

}
@media all and (max-width: 1920px){

}
@media all and (max-width: 1440px){

}
@media all and (max-width: 1280px){

}
@media all and (max-width: 1200px){

}
@media all and (max-width: 1024px){

}
@media all and (max-width: 992px){

}
@media all and (max-width: 768px){

}
@media all and (max-width: 720px){

}
@media all and (max-width: 600px){

}
@media all and (max-width: 540px){

}
@media all and (max-width: 480px){

}
@media all and (max-width: 424px){

}
@media all and (max-width: 414px){

}
@media all and (max-width: 400px){

}
@media all and (max-width: 384px){

}
@media all and (max-width: 375px){

}
@media all and (max-width: 360px){

}
@media all and (max-width: 320px){

}
```